# equals in c# is true

Tags: c#, equals, webmethod

I am doing webmethod in c#. On debugging,

```
(chk.Equals(oldpass))
```

the query shows same value on both left and right side.

But still,instead of going inside if,execution moves to else part showing return statement.
Foll. is my code.

```
[WebMethod (Description="for change in password")]
public string update(string authenid,string oldpass,string newpass)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Workspace\\visual studio workspace\\Tmrepo\\App_Data\\tmrepo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

  string chk = "select pwd from client where authenid = '"+ @authenid +"' ";
        if(chk.Equals(oldpass))
        {
            string update = "update client set pwd=@newpass where pwd=@oldpass and authenid=@authenid";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authenid", authenid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpass", oldpass);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpass", newpass);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        else
        {
            return "invalid oldpass";
        }
 conn.Close();
        return newpass;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

Is anything wrong in this code? I am a c# newbie.
Thanks.

Comment: where is the code to extract password first?

Comment: is `oldpass`also a query? where is it set?

Comment: posted the complt code...

Comment: This code compares the password value to the string "select pwd from client where authenid = 1". If the user does have that exact password, it will go to the else branch.

Comment: completed your missing code, i am now sure how you are consufed! but what you did was constructed a sql string and was checking it against password!

Comment: You should learn about password hashing and SQL injection.

Comment: @CodeCaster - how does sql injection n hashing comes into play?

Comment: his codes have missing logic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,solved!!! I used dataset. The second method with perfectly correct code is :

```
string chk = "select pwd from client where authenid = @authenid";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(chk , conn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authenid", authenid);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        da.Fill(ds);
        int cnt = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pwd"].ToString().Equals(oldpass))
            {
                string update = "update client set pwd=@newpass where pwd=@oldpass and authenid=@authenid";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authenid", authenid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpass", oldpass);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpass", newpass);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }            
        }
```

Hope it helps other newbies like me!!

Answer (score 5):

You haven't executed the command: your old password chk is: "select pwd from client where authenid = '"+ @authenid +"' ";, which is an unlikely password. Look into ExecuteScalar, for example.

Additional thoughts:

- *parameterize* the sql - don't concatenate the id in; it should be `"select pwd from client where authenid = @authenid";` where you are adding a parameter named `authenid` with the value from `authenid`. You get this right in the second ADO.NET query.
- passwords should be salted and hashed: not stored directly; you should never be able to extract and/or decrypt a password

---

(external edits)

**Update**: Execute code as `"select pwd from client where authenid = '"+ @authenid +"' ";` because `"select pwd from client where authenid = '@authenid' ";` returns null value.

**update2**:
`cmd.ExecuteScalar();` made it work. And remove `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: +1, Also this type of password is well known to be valid and need to be special cased ;) http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4):

what your code doing is comparing `select pwd from client where authenid = some_value` against the value of oldpass, which will be false!

Fixed Code Logic :

```
        string oldpass = "somehing";

        string authenid = "pass_to_test";
        string sql = string.Format("select pwd from client where authenid = '{0}' ", authenid);
        string chk = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            // has record with username
            chk = reader.GetString(0);
            if (chk.Equals(oldpass))
            {
                string update = "update client set pwd=@newpass where pwd=@oldpass and authenid=@authenid";

                cmd.CommandText = update;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authenid", authenid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpass", oldpass);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newpass", newpass);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            else
            {
                return "invalid oldpass";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // not a valid username
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
```

Comment: Don't use String.Format to build queries.

Comment: @Shachi - the code is a logic, u need to adjust it as per your need!

Comment: @Shachi - updated the code, there was line missing, `cmd.CommandText = update;` sql for updatecommand need to be set!